# Virtual box - Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

First of all I used to have Ubuntu in Windows 7. So that's all about my first pc. I run simulations using open foam and other programs such as parafoam. So today I upgrade my old pc. In my newer system I also have Windows 7 but now I 've got another storage device. I want to ask if there is a way to connect my old hdd and paste all files and system programs to my new virtual machine. Or if I can make a new virtual machine around my old pc.
So the specs are the following.
First pc: i5 650 - p7p55d motherboard - 300gb he'd ( where I used to have Windows and Ubuntu)
New pc: i7 - 16gb ram - ga x99 motherboard - 120gb ssd as well as the old hdd also connected.

On my previous pc I used to to host Ubuntu in Windows using virtualbox. Now on my new pc I have an ssd to boot Windows I 've got the old hdd from my first pc but also another ssd where I want to run Ubuntu again. Canofcolliders thank you for the answer it worked that way. But I have my new virtualbox in my ads and I boot Ubuntu from my hdd where all my files are. I want to migrate all files to my ssd where my new virtual machine has installed and also use the entire drive for my work. I say that because on my hdd where I used to run I had only 50Gb of free space, so even now I get messages about disk space that is full. To be clear once again I want to transfer files from my hdd to my new ssd at a new pc with whole different specs than the older one. And boot Ubuntu with all my files (openfoam, parafoam, etc) from the ssd.

Comment: It is unclear whether you run Windows in VirtualBox on top of Ubuntu, or the other way around.  It is further unclear what you want to do.  If you want to transfer an Ubuntu VirtualBox installation from one Windows machine to another, then this question may be off topic here as it has to do with file copying on Windows. Please clarify your question.

Comment: it seems pretty clear that the OP is running an Ubuntu VM on a Win 7 host.

Answer (score 2):

If i understand you right you have your old hdd already connected in your new pc?
Why not just import your old virtual machine into VirtualBox on your new pc then, instead of 
trying to migrate all settings/files from one vm to another?

A virtual machine is just a file. 
Go to your old computers HDD and try to find the VM, if you didn't customize the path it's probably under

> Users\YourUsername\VirtualBox VMs\

in Windows 7.

Look for a *.vbox file (the configuration), accompanied by a pretty big (probably *.vdi) file (the VM). 
Once you found it, open VirtualBox, select

> Machine > Add

and import the *.vbox file. 
All your settings should carry over, and you should be able to use that VM just as before.